# Как один класс может реализовать 2 интерфейса?

Tags: java, typescript, шаблоны-проектирования

Читаю книгу по паттернам (паттерны проектирования, Эрик и Элизабет Фримен. 42 ст.):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

там объясняется одно неверное решение, где один класс должен реализовать два интерфейса (Quackable, Flyable). Сам изучаю TypeScript, а книга написана под Java, но, ни в первом, ни во втором языке не нашел такой возможности. Как один класс может реализовать 2 интерфейса?

Comment: Java и TypeScript - очень разные языки. Вы пытаетесь учить турецкий по учебнику английского, образно говоря. По сути вопроса: Во-первых, авторы ещё во введении написали, что от читателя требуется знание языка. Во-вторых, в читаемой вами книге есть пример `public class CurrentConditionsDisplay implements Observer, DisplayElement`.

Comment: В книге на стр. 33 есть ссылка на примеры кода. Скачайте его и изучайте.
Хорошая книга! Upd: ссылка вроде как устарела (404), но по ключевым словам можно выйти на обновленную версию:
[Тыць!](https://www.wickedlysmart.com/head-first-design-patterns/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я понимаю что не стоит учить книгу не зная языка используемого в книге, но очень уж интересно она написана. Можно узнать не только проблему и решение, а так же как эта проблема возникла и как разработчик пытается ее решить. Для typescript к сожалению такой книги пока не нашел.

Answer (score 5):

```
interface Flyable {
  fly();
}

interface Quackable {
  quack();
}

class Duck implements Flyable, Quackable {
  fly() {
    // Do fly;
  }

  quack() {
    // Do quack;
  }
}
```